# How do I compare vertices?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, vertices

Is there any easy way to compare if features in one set are sharing vertices?

If I am cutting parcels and I want the next parcel over to have the same vertices?

I converted my vertices to points, and then used find identical to determine the mismatch.  Something similar to this but not as cumbersome.

Comment: Are you familiar with topology? Look up topology rules for ArcGIS.

Comment: Which software are you using?

Comment: 10.4.1 - I don't have data reviewer.  I can't find anything in the topology rules that would relate to vertices other than a tolerance?